# CSS, wanting to align an item to the left of a centered div with some spacing around it?

Tags: html, css, center

I have a container div, with two children divs:

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="child1">
    I want this to be displayed next to the child2 div, 
    but offset to the right by about 3em. Basically, 
    I want spacing between it and the second child, 
    but I want the second child to remain centered.
    </div>

    <div id="child2">
    I want this to be centered on the page
    </div>

</div>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to keep the second child centered along the page horizontally while adding some spacing between it and the first child div. Does anyone know how to do this? I'm using the following css but can't get the second div to have padding between it and the first div.

I have the following css but can't quite get it working:

```
#container {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#child1, #child2 {
    display: inline-flex;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;    
}

#container #child1{
  border: 5px solid red;  
  margin-right:30%;
/*margin-right:50%;*/
}


#container #child2{
  border: 5px solid green;  
  margin-left:30%;
  margin-right:30%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

    <div id="child1">
    <p>I want this to be displayed next to the child2 div, 
    but offset to the right by about 3em. Basically, 
    I want spacing between it and the second child, 
    but I want the second child to remain centered.</p>
    </div>
<br>
<br>
    <div id="child2">
      <p>I want this to be centered on the page</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Hey Jason,
I hope you are doing well.

You can control the margin of the divs, to center you will set both left and right to 30%, and to set the dive to the left side of your screen you will add a margin of 30% to the right, so it is pushing away from the right side  of the screen 30%, you can increase to 50% if you wish it to be further away from the right side of the screen and closest to the left.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MsZa.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOFfN.png)

Answer (score 0):

What about use flex?
I don't know whether I figure out your meaning. But flex is a good tool for layout. 
Here has a good guide for flex: https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties

```css
#container {
    margin: auto;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}
#child1{
  padding-right:3em;
}
#child2 {
  padding-top:3em;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="child1">
    I want this to be displayed next to the child2 div, 
    but offset to the right by about 3em. Basically, 
    I want spacing between it and the second child, 
    but I want the second child to remain centered.
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
    I want this to be centered on the page
    </div>
</div>
```